# Prove that intersection of cyclic subgroup is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> The intersection of cyclic groups is cyclic, [source of claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889172/showing-that-if-the-intersection-of-all-subgroups-other-than-langle-e-rangle)

### My attempt  at proof:

Definition of a cyclic subgroup:

> A cyclic group is a group which is equal to one of its cyclic subgroups: $G = \langle g\rangle $ for some element $g$, called a generator.

If one proves for the statement that "intersection of two cyclic subgroup is cyclic", then the statement naturally extends through induction for countable number of cyclic subgroup.(*)

We know that [intersection of subgroup is a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253394/if-p-leq-g-q-leq-g-are-p-cap-q-and-p-cup-q-subgroups-of-g). What is left is to prove that this subgroup can be generated out of some element.

Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of a group $G$ generated by elements $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle $ respectively. Intuition tells me that this element which generates the cyclic subgroup must have order $\gcd( |a|,|b|)$ , but how do I show an element with such an order exists so I can generate the whole intersection subgroup out of it?

*: Not sure how to show it's true for uncountable case.

Comment: *"the statement naturally extends through induction for higher number of cyclic subgroup."* - but what about the intersection of uncountably many cyclic groups?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, what I would do then.. @Shaun

Comment: Nontrivial elements of the cyclic group $\Bbb Z$ are all of infinite order.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of your last comment to the proof. $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable only , right? @Shaun

Comment: I mean $\gcd(|a|,|b|)$ might be infinite. Initially, I thought that was a problem, but upon reflection now, it's fine; sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All subgroups of any cyclic group are cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295564/104041) The intersection $H$ of cyclic groups $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ for any index set $I$ is a subgroup of each $G_i$. Hence $H$ is cyclic.

Comment: Actually now I think of it. You need to show that intersection of subgroups is a subgroup of the original subgroups intersected for applying theorem in linked. I only linked to intersection being subgroup of total group. It's a trivial thing to prove but I can't find the link...

Comment: Use the one-step subgroup test, @Buraian.

Comment: Could you please remark on what the order of generator should be?

Comment: That's a separate question, @Buraian. If you cannot find it here, I suggest you ask it in a new post.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395659/let-h-and-k-be-subgroups-of-a-finite-cyclic-group-g-prove-h-cap-k?rq=1